# Bringing a function into a lexical environment

Tags: functions, lexical-scoping

**I'm using a closure to keep track of some stuff to do with state**; **I want to be
able to ‘include’ a function into that closure**, so it can access the state. The
only way this is possible is by *creating* that function inside the closure.

My idea is to have a function `include`, itself created inside that lexical
environment, which takes a *quoted* lambda form, and then returns the actual
function (which will have been created inside the closure).

Given that `lambda` is actually a macro which expands to <s>another macro call</s>

```
(function (lambda ...))
```

my best attempt has been

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(let ((x 0)) ;; to represent some state variable
  (defun include (quoted-lambda)
    (eval
     (macroexpand quoted-lambda)
     t))) ;; last `t' is to eval with lexical binding
```

and then

```
(defalias 'incx (include '(lambda ()
                            (incf x))))

(incx) ;; should get 1
```

but this just results in  `(void-variable x)`!

**How can this be fixed?**

Comment: Did you put a local-variable declaration for `lexical-binding` at the top of the containing file? That's needed, to get proper `lexical-binding` behavior.

Comment: @Drew; I did put the `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` in; does `eval-buffer` take note of it? (That's what I was using to run the thing.) **EDIT:** yup, `eval-buffer` is affected by that header, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: No: `eval-buffer` does not look at the header:  it's `find-file` (and its ilks) which does.  Along the same lines the `lambda` macro does not expands to another macro call `function` is not a macro but a special form).

Comment: @Stefan; fixed `function` misunderstanding in question. The point about the header was just to make sure that lexical binding was on, but thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying here to access the lexical variable `x` from outside its lexical scope, which obviously can't work.  What you can do is pass a lexical environment to `eval`:

> LEXICAL can also be an actual lexical environment, in the form of an
>   alist mapping symbols to their value.

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun include (quoted-lambda)
  (eval quoted-lambda
        ;; Using a quoted constant means all expressions returned by
        ;; `include' will share the same environment.  Use `copy-tree'
        ;; to get indenpendent copies.
        '((x . 0))))

;and then

(require 'cl-lib)
(defalias 'incx (include '(lambda ()
                            (cl-incf x))))

(incx) ;; should get 1
```

Comment: Nice! Out of interest, do you think there's a cleaner way to do this? (Maybe using EIEIO, or in a different way.)

Comment: @digitalis_: It's hard to say without seeing more context about what "do this" means.

Comment: fair enough! "Do this" means allowing certain functions to reference some state (in my case, it's actually a timer, which is a function that takes either `:start` or `:stop`) privately.

Comment: @digitalis_: What's wrong with having all the functions under the same `let`? Or, just using a global variable, it'll probably be easier to debug (the state is always easily inspectable). PS the `macroexpand` is not needed (`eval` already does macroexpansion), I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want is access to the lexical-environment of a function, which would allow something like this

```el
(let ...
  (defun include (lambda-form)
    (eval lambda-form
          (this-lexical-environment))))
```

But such a function does not exist and while there is a variable `internal-interpreter-environment`, it's not accessible via Lisp. But let's remember how closures are constructed:

```el
(let ((x 0))
  (lambda () (* x x)))
;; => (closure ((x . 0) t) nil (* x x))
```

So it seems that we can access the environment of a closure.

```el
(butlast (cadr (let ((x 0))
                 (lambda () (* x x)))))
;; => ((x . 0))
```

Armed with this knowledge, we can write a function, which injects the environment of one closure into a second one.

```el
(defun lexenv-grant-access (from to)
  "Grant access of FROM's lexenv to TO."
  (let (name env)
    (when (symbolp from)
      (setq from (symbol-function from)))
    (when (symbolp to)
      (setq name to
            to (symbol-function to)))
    (pcase from
      (`(closure ,env-form ,args . ,body)
       (setq env (butlast env-form)))
      (_ (error "FROM is not a closure")))
    (pcase to
      (`(closure ,env-form ,args . ,body)
       (eval
        (if name
            `(defalias ',name (lambda ,args ,@body))
          `(lambda ,args ,@body))
        (append (butlast env-form)
                env)))
      (_ (error "TO is not a closure")))))

(let ((x 0))
  (defun incx ()
    (cl-incf x)))

(defun decx ()
  (cl-decf x))

(decx)
;; => (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)

(lexenv-grant-access 'incx 'decx)
(list (incx) (decx))
;; => (1 0)
```

So what are the problems ?  First, this uses an internal implementation detail, i.e. how closure lists are constructed.  But more importantly, it won't work with compiled functions.  Such a function has a completely different structure and it may not even store the names of the variables, only their values.

```el
;;Byte compiling the function's file...
(symbol-function 'incx)
;; => #[0 "\300\211\242T\240\207" [(0)] 2]
(disassemble 'incx) ;; => ...
```

Can you spot the value of `x` ? Anyway, I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: I think this is the sort of stuff Voldemort does with Emacs. Evil? Yes. But tempting...

Answer (score 1):

To "give access" to a variable, you simply have to *pass it* to the closure:

```
(let ((x 0))
  (defun include (fun)
    (funcall fun x)))
```

Of course, in your case, you really want to pass the state itself rather than the state's value.  You can do that in the following way, using `gv-ref`

```
(let* ((x 0)
       (xref (gv-ref x)))
  (defun include (fun)
    (funcall fun xref)))

(defun incx (xref)
  (cl-incf (gv-deref xref)))
```

Where `gv-ref` is like C's `&` and `gv-deref` is like C's `*`.

Of course, you can also do it without gv, as in:

```
(let ((xref (cons 0 nil)))
  (defun include (fun)
    (funcall fun xref)))

(defun incx (xref)
  (cl-incf (car xref)))
```