# `eval` in `rx-to-string` works in `*scratch*` but not in code

Tags: rx

I am trying to code an `rx-to-string` form that contains an intermediate regexp.

This code works in Lisp Interaction Mode:

```
(let* ((a-plus '(one-or-more "a")))
  (rx-to-string '(sequence (eval a-plus))))
```

but fails in Emacs Lisp Mode with a `(void-variable a-plus)` error. Why? How do I fix that?

EDIT: I have found the cause: the `lexical-binding: t` directive in the Emacs Lisp buffer.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me in both modes. If you replace '(sequence (eval a-plus)) with `(sequence ,a-plus) does it work for you?

Comment: @JohnKitchin I have found the cause: the `lexical-binding: t` directive in the Emacs Lisp Buffer. Anyway, your alternative works, thanks.

Comment: If you have found the solution, please post it as an answer and then accept that answer as soon as the system allows you. Self-answers are totally fine (encouraged, in fact).

Comment: Similar to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/why-does-this-straightforward-use-of-a-closure-fail (not an exact dup, since the use of `rx-to-string` adds some wrinkles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `rx-to-string` does not work with `lexical-binding: t`, because of `eval` (see also:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30174/2763).

However, the workaround proposed by @JohnKitchin works:

```
(let* ((a-plus '(one-or-more "a")))
  (rx-to-string `(sequence ,a-plus)))
```